# Substring file name in Unix using sed command

Tags: sed

I want to substring the File name in unix using `sed` command.

File name : `Test_Test1_Test2_10082019_030013.csv.20191008-075740`

I want the characters after the 3rd underscore or (all the characters after Test2 ) i need to be printed .

Can this be done using `sed` command?

I have tried this command

```
sed 's/^.*_\([^_]*\)$/\1/' <<< 'Test_Test1_Test2_10082019_030013.csv.20191008-075740'
```

but this is giving result as `030013.csv.20191008-075740` 
I need it from `10082019_030013.csv.20191008-075740`

Thanks
Neha

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this command ...  sed 's/^.*_\([^_]*\)$/\1/' <<< 'Test_Test1_Test2_10082019_030013.csv.20191008-075740' , But i am getting the output 030013.csv.20191008-075740. I need it from 10082019_030013.csv.20191008-075740

Comment: @NehaSingh, Good that you showed your efforts, comments are not meant for adding code, so always try to add these in your question itself, cheers and happy learning.

Answer (score 3):

To remove from the beginning up to including the 3rd underscore you can use

```
sed 's/^\([^_]*_\)\{3\}//' <<< 'Test_Test1_Test2_10082019_030013.csv.20191008-075740'
```

This removes the initial part that consists of 3 groups of (any number of non-underscore characters followed by an underscore). The result is

```
10082019_030013.csv.20191008-075740
```

If you use GNU `sed` you can switch it to extended regular expressions and omit the backslashes.

```
sed -r 's/^([^_]*_){3}//' <<< 'Test_Test1_Test2_10082019_030013.csv.20191008-075740'
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
sed 's/\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)_\(.*\)/\4/'  Input_file
```

Or as per Bodo's nice suggestion:

```
sed 's/[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]_\(.*\)/\1/' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/_/\n/3;s/.*\n//;t;s/Test2/\n/;s/.*\n//;t;d' file
```

Replace the third `_` by a newline and then remove everything upto and including the first newline. If this succeeds, bail out and print the result. Otherwise, try the same method with `Test2` and if this fails delete the entire line.